# Python: Merging dictionary lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge, iterator

I have lists inside a dictionary:

```
Number_of_lists=3           #user sets this value, can be any positive integer
My_list={}
for j in range(1,Number_of_lists+1):
  My_list[j]=[(x,y,z)]
```

The `Number_of_lists` is a variable set by the user. Without knowing beforehand the value set by the user, i would like to finally have a merged list of all dictionary lists. For example if `Number_of_lists=3` and the corresponding lists are `My_list[1]=[(1,2,3)]` , `My_list[2]=[(4,5,6)]` , `My_list[3]=[(7,8,9)]` the result would be:

```
All_my_lists=My_list[1]+My_list[2]+My_list[3]
```

where:
`All_my_lists=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]`.

So what i'm trying to do is automate the above procedure for all possible:

`Number_of_lists=n    #where n can be any positive integer`

I'm a bit lost up to now trying to use an iterator to add the lists up and always fail. I'm a python beginner and this is a hobby of mine, so if you answer please explain everything in your answer i'm doing this to learn, i'm not asking from you to do my homework  :)

### **EDIT**

@codebox (look at the comments below) correctly pointed out that `My_List` as displayed in my code is in fact a dictionary and not a list. Be careful if you use any of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a list comprehension:

```
>>> Number_of_lists=3 
>>> My_list={}
>>> for j in range(1,Number_of_lists+1):
      My_list[j]=(j,j,j)
>>> All_my_lists=[My_list[x] for x in My_list]

>>> print(All_my_lists)
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

`All_my_lists=[My_list[x] for x in My_list]` is equivalent to:

```
All_my_lists=[]
for key in My_list:
   All_my_lists.append(My_list[key])
```

Comment: This may be fine for this case and the particular python implementation at hand, but in general one can't assume that the list of keys (returned by "for x in My_list") of a dictionary are in sorted order for every length of dict or particular python interpreter/platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned with the final list, and don't actually need `My_list` (which you should rename, because its a dictionary!) then you could just do:

```
Number_of_lists=3
result = []
for j in range(1,Number_of_lists+1):
    result += (x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to generate `All_my_lists` first followed by `My_list`.

#### Building `All_my_lists`

Using [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) and [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) to generate `All_my_lists`:

```
>>> num = 3  # for brevity, I changed Number_of_lists to num
>>> All_my_lists = [tuple(range(num*i + 1, num*(i+1) + 1)) for i in range(0, num)]
>>> All_my_lists
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

Alternatively, we can use the `grouper()` function from list of [itertools recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) which will result in a much cleaner code:

```
>>> All_my_lists = list(grouper(num, range(1, num*3+1)))
>>> All_my_lists
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

#### Building `My_lists`

We can then use [`dict` constructor](http://mainlydata.kubadev.com/python/the-python-dict-constructor/) along with list comprehension and [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to build derive `My_list` from `All_my_list`:

```
>>> My_lists = dict((i+1, [v]) for i,v in enumerate(All_my_lists))
>>> My_lists
{1: [(1, 2, 3)], 2: [(4, 5, 6)], 3: [(7, 8, 9)]}
>>> My_lists[1]
[(1, 2, 3)]
>>> My_lists[2]
[(4, 5, 6)]
>>> My_lists[3]
[(7, 8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a more functional approach by turning `Number_of_lists` into a sequence of keys using `range` and select out of the dictionary with `map`:

```
My_list={1:[1,2,3], 2:[4,5,6], 3:[7,8,9], 4:[10,11,12]}
Number_of_lists=3
All_my_lists=map(lambda x: tuple(My_list[x]), range(1, Number_of_lists+1))
```

Example output:

```
>>> All_my_lists
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```